# Plotting points with different colors according to their local density

Tags: plotting

I have the position of some points in the 2D plane. How can I plot points in the 2D plane, with different colors so that, each color shows the local density of points? I need denser points to be in different color comparing with lower dencity points

Comment: This: [6081](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/6081/5478) or that: [27786](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/27786/5478)?

Comment: Is there a way to show a unit vector in the position of each particle? @Kuba

Comment: Yes they are. thank you for the links/

Comment: How can I show larger points?@Kuba

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If not those links then probably this:

```
data = RandomVariate[BinormalDistribution[.75], 50];

d = SmoothKernelDistribution[data];


colors = Rescale[#, MinMax[#], {0, 1}] & @ PDF[d, data];

Graphics[
 {AbsolutePointSize@12,
  Point[data, VertexColors -> (Blend["TemperatureMap", #] & /@ colors)]
  }
 ]
```

You can play with bandwidth:

```
data = RandomVariate[BinormalDistribution[{0, 0}, {.4, .7}, .5], 200];

Animate[
  d = SmoothKernelDistribution[data, 10.^bw]
; colors = Blend["TemperatureMap", #
  ] & /@ Rescale[#, MinMax[#], {0, 1}] & @ PDF[d, data]

; Graphics[{
      Inset[Style[NumberForm[10.^bw, {∞, 2}], Bold, 18], Scaled[{.2, .8}]]
    , AbsolutePointSize@12, Point[data, VertexColors -> colors]
    }
  , Frame -> True
  , PlotRange -> 2
  , ImageSize -> 500
  , Background -> Black
  , FrameStyle -> White
  ]
, {bw, -2, 1, .2}
]
```

[image]

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/68521/discussion-between-kuba-and-oliver-range).