# Converting 3d points into a density plot

Tags: plotting, graphics, graphics3d

Is there a way to convert an array of values $(x_i,y_i,z_i), i=1,\ldots,n$ to a density plot instead of a `ListPointPlot3D`?

I don't know if this is duplicated, but somehow, I cannot seem to just use `ListDensityPlot3D`?

Comment: Notice that ListDensityPlot does not work with just points either. You can do something like this: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/159644/5478 in 3D. Which seems to work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hard to know exactly what you want without the explicit data, but maybe you'd like to bin the data?

```
SeedRandom[1234];
pts = RandomReal[{0, 1}, {1000, 3}];

centers = Tuples[Range[.1, .9, .2], 3];

nf = Nearest[centers];

ListDensityPlot3D[KeyValueMap[Append, CountsBy[pts, First@*nf]]]
```

[image]

Comment: Hi Chip, something like this is the kind of thing exactly! But is it possible, rather than grey and orange, to have high density regions be more opaque and low density more transparent?

Comment: See `OpacityFunction` in the `ListDensityPlot3D` ref page [here](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ListDensityPlot3D.html#39466749).

Answer (score 4):

Using Chip Hurst's example data:

```
SeedRandom[1234];
pts = RandomReal[{0, 1}, {1000, 3}];
```

#### SmoothKernelDistribution + DensityPlot3D

```
pdf[x_, y_, z_] := PDF[SmoothKernelDistribution[pts, MaxExtraBandwidths -> 0, 
   MaxMixtureKernels -> All], {x, y, z}]
DensityPlot3D[Evaluate[pdf[x, y, z]], {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}, {z, 0, 1},
  ColorFunction -> (Directive[Opacity[#], Blend[{{0, White}, {0.5, Blue}, {1, Red}}, #]] &), 
 PlotLegends -> Automatic]
```

[image]

```
DensityPlot3D[Evaluate[pdf[x, y, z]], {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}, {z, 0, 1},
  OpacityFunction -> Function[f, f/20],
 ColorFunction -> (Blend[{{0, White}, {0.5, Blue}, {1, Red}}, #] &), 
 PlotLegends -> Automatic]
```

[image]

#### HistogramList + ListDensityPlot3D

```
ListDensityPlot3D[HistogramList[pts, 10][[2]], DataRange -> {{0, 1}, {0, 1}, {0, 1}}]
```

[image]

Comment: This is the kind of thing kglr, is there a way to change it so the density points is displayed as a function of opacity? ie the more points in a neighbourhood, the denser the opacity/region?

Comment: @MKF, i updated with a `ColorFunction` that makes denser regions more opaque.

Comment: Wow you are amazing, thank you so much for your guidance!