# ListDensityPlot3D with opacity

Tags: plotting, graphics3d

Suppose I have a bunch of 3d data points, is there a way to plot a `ListDensityPlot3D` such that the opacity is determined by the number of nearest points to each datapoint?

Meaning, in dense point regions, the view is more opaque, and in less dense regions, the transparency increases?

Comment: Can you share a dataset to play with?

Comment: Sure, two seconds

Comment: How about the $\kappa=4$ case from https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/13038/vectors-with-a-certain-magnitude-in-mathematica, where there is an overdensity in the top left, or even the $\kappa=8,16$ case. Thanks

Comment: I am not sure I completely understand. You need 4D points as input for `ListDensityPlot3D`, i.e. $(x,y,z,f)$. What should the value of $f$ be for your points? I was hoping you could share an actual data set in MMA format for us to play with. Also, if your points are denser, and they are represented by a non-transparent symbol in a 3D plot, wouldn't the effect you seek sort of happen naturally? That is, where you have more points, there plot is less transparent because of the points themselves?

Comment: $f$ would probably be the number of nearest neighbours in this example

Comment: "That is, where you have more points, there plot is less transparent because of the points themselves?" - Exactly; perhaps a better way of phrasing it would be to smooth the points out instead of ListDensityPlot them?

Comment: Does this question lead you to the solution? https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/191298/4346

Comment: When I asked that, this differs slightly because I ask that the density be mirrored by the local density of a point. You could for example imagine identical spheres around each point, count the number of points in the sphere to estimate the local density, then use this parameter to plot an opacity in the vicinity of each point. They are related

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using J.M.'s [`vonMisesFisherRandom`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/13038/vectors-with-a-certain-magnitude-in-mathematica):

```
SeedRandom[1]
table = With[{μ = {-1/Sqrt[8], -Sqrt[3/8], 1/Sqrt[2]}, κ =  4}, 
  Table[vonMisesFisherRandom[μ, κ], {10^3}]];
radius = .05;
data = DeleteDuplicatesBy[Join[table, 
  List /@ Length /@ Nearest[table, table, {All, radius}], 2], #[[;; 3]] &];
Row[{ListPointPlot3D[table, PlotStyle -> AbsolutePointSize[1], 
   ImageSize -> Medium, BoxRatios -> 1], 
  ListDensityPlot3D[data, 
   ColorFunction -> (Opacity[N@Log[# + 1], Blend[{{0, White}, {1, Red}}, #]] &),
   ImageSize -> Medium, 
   PlotLegends -> Automatic]}]
```

[image]

You can also use the option [`OpacityFunction`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/OpacityFunction.html) as follows:

```
ListDensityPlot3D[data, 
 OpacityFunction -> (#/5 &), 
 ImageSize -> Medium, PlotLegends -> Automatic]
```

[image]

Add the option `ColorFunction -> (Blend[{{0, White}, {1, Red}}, #]&)` to get

[image]

Comment: Very nice, thanks! Is there a way to recover somehow the "smoothness" of the points distribution? It looks very red in that region on the left!

Comment: @MKF, maybe we can use  some non-linear scaling like `Sqrt` instead of `Rescale[...]`?

Comment: Let's check it out :)

Comment: @MKF, please see the updated version.

Comment: Looking great - it kind of matches the effect here using contours https://www.blendswap.com/blends/view/89381 which seems to have this sort of effect you plotted above